# Get a list of tuples containing files with the same names but different endings

Tags: python

I have a folder which among others contains pairs of json and jpeg files with the same file names. Based on this folder, I want to create a list of tuples containing the pairs as follows:

```
[('first.json','first.jpg'),('second.json','second.jpg')...('last.json','last.jpg')]
```

Filtering for only json and and jpg files is easy:

```
import os
import re
files = [targetFile for targetFile in os.listdir('Z:/data') if re.match('.*\.json|.*\.jpg', targetFile)]
print(files)
```

But how can I combine that part with the generation of the list of tuples without iterating through the file list for a second time?

Comment: The code snippet I posted creates a list containing all json and jpeg files in a folder. What I actually need is a list of tuples, where the tuples contain all files with the same names but different endings (like the example list I posted). How can I modify my code to achieve that?

Comment: Couldn't you could use a regular `for` loop instead of a closure?

Comment: True - and work with dictionaries instead of tuples, using the file name as keys. That would prevent several iterations through the same set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for that compact way of doing this,

ps: note that this returns list of lists instead of list of tuples,

```
# bunch of files os.listdir() returns
files = ['first.jpg', 'first.json', 'second.jpg', 'second.json']

print([re.findall(fileName + r'(?:.jpg|.json)', ' '.join(files)) \
       for fileName in set(re.findall(r'(\w*?)(?:\.jpg|\.json)', ' '.join(files)))])

# [['second.jpg', 'second.json'], ['first.jpg', 'first.json']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, per your comments:

```
files, tuples = list(), list()
for targetFile in os.listdir('Z:/data'):
    if re.match('.*\.json|.*\.jpg', targetFile):
        files.append(targetFile)
        tuples.append((...))
```

...where in the ellipsis you place code that extracts the filenames and appends the endings.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @John Perry, who reminded me of the fact that style shouldn't prevail over functionality, I came up with the following simple solution:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
listOfRelevantFiles = defaultdict(list)
for targetFile in os.listdir('Z:/data'):
    if '.jpg' in targetFile or '.json' in targetFile:
        listOfRelevantFiles[targetFile.split('.')[0]].append(targetFile)
print(listOfRelevantFiles)
```